# trying to change a data type in table using a query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query

```
CREATE TABLE COSTUMER(
    COSTUMER_ID INT,
    TAXI_ID INT,
    COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER BIGINT,
    COSTUMER_NAME VARCHAR(40),
    DESTINATION VARCHAR(40)
);
```

i'd like to change the `DESTINATION` data type to `DATETIME` rather than `VARCHAR`. or if you can suggest a better data type that can store a full address the please do.

I tried this query

```
ALTER TABLE COSTUMER ALTER DESTINATION DATETIME
```

but when executed I get this message :

> 102 stating expecting column

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html  `alter ... alter` has a different purpose than what you're using. you want `alter ... change` or `alter ... modify`

Comment: An address as in a postal address? Why do you want to store it as a datetime?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a mySql database then the syntax should be as follows:

ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype

Answer (score 0):

```
 ALTER TABLE COSTUMER MODIFY COLUMN DESTINATION DATETIME;
```